# Como criar simbolo entre diretórios no deploy PHP com Deployer?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, deploy

Eu estava criando uma aplicação em Laravel, e estou utilizando o Deployer. Este é o arquivo de configuração das pastas que estará a pasta releases ( que são as versões do projeto ) e a pasta current ( que ficará o projeto atual )

```
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';

// Project name
set('application', 'my_project');

// Project repository
set('repository', 'https://github.com/Genielson/lara-code.git');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true); 

// Shared files/dirs between deploys 
add('shared_files', []);
add('shared_dirs', []);

// Writable dirs by web server 
add('writable_dirs', []);


// Hosts

host('meuacesso.host')
    ->port('minhaporta')
    ->set('writable_mode', 'chmod')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/html');    
    
// Tasks

task('build', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} && build');
});

// [Optional] if deploy fails automatically unlock.
after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');

// Migrate database before symlink new release.

//before('deploy:symlink', 'artisan:migrate');
```

O problema é que em ambientes compartilhados com Apache, a pasta principal onde se deve colocar o projeto fica em /home/defaultwebsite/public/  e onde o Deployer joga o projeto é em /var/www/html/. Nesse ultimo caminho o Deployer criará a pasta current e releases. A minha duvida é :  Como que eu faço para essa pasta public apontar para a pasta current? Ouvi pessoas falando que tenho que criar um link simbólico para essa pasta. Algueḿ sabe como fazer isso? Ou melhor, sabem me falar se essa realmente é a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Porque não modificar o [*DocumentRoot* do *virtualhost*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) do Apache para ele apontar para o local correto? Poderia também modificar a pasta onde o deploy será feito.

Comment: Perdão, mas não tenho tanta experiencia em editar o DocumentRoot. Poderia me dizer ou mostrar algum tutorial fazendo mais ou menos isso?

Comment: http://devfuria.com.br/linux/apache-ajustando-documentroot/